# Room Database migration freezes screen

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

The code below is the database builder code and migration code.
When there's big data and migration happens the screen freezes and a black screen appears until the database is built.
Is there a way to handle this problem better and more user-friendly (i.e showing a loading dialog)?

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MainDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            MainDatabase::class.java,
            databaseName
        )
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .openHelperFactory(provideSupportFactory(context.applicationContext))
            .addMigrations(X)
            .build()
    }

    val X = object : Migration(2, 3) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
               database.execSQL("SOME KIND OF SQL STATEMENT")
                }
```

And the function that calls the database is:

`fun openDatabase(){ getInstance(requireContext()) }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is recommended not to use allowMainThreadQueries() for Android room?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999851/why-is-recommended-not-to-use-allowmainthreadqueries-for-android-room)

Comment: @StanislavBondar removing this line causes ANR, so it's not the right soloution.

Comment: As you've said when there is big data the screen freezes is because you are running the migration on main thread. It is not the recommended way because it may run smooth where data is less but with huge dataset it's gonna cause problems with not only the migration but the other queries as well. It will freeze the UI every time you run a database query. Just remove the **allowMainThreadQueries()** from your code and create database object on a background thread. That will solve your problem.